# When I train my caffe model, the loss always keeps a large value and the accuracy does not improve．

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

This is the result I get when I train my own model

```
I0510 20:53:16.677439  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0510 20:57:20.822933  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 3.78788e-05
I0510 20:57:20.823001  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 9.27223 (* 1 = 9.27223 loss)
I0510 20:57:21.423084  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 0, loss = 9.29181
I0510 20:57:21.423110  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 9.29181 (* 1 = 9.29181 loss)
I0510 20:57:21.423120  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = 0.001
I0510 21:06:57.498831  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1000, Testing net (#0)
I0510 21:10:59.477396  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00186553
I0510 21:10:59.477463  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.86572 (* 1 = 8.86572 loss)
I0510 21:20:35.828510  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2000, Testing net (#0)
I0510 21:24:42.838196  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00144886
I0510 21:24:42.838245  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.83859 (* 1 = 8.83859 loss)
I0510 21:24:43.412120  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2000, loss = 8.81461
I0510 21:24:43.412145  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.81461 (* 1 = 8.81461 loss)
I0510 21:24:43.412150  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2000, lr = 0.001
I0510 21:38:50.990823  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 3000, Testing net (#0)
I0510 21:42:52.918418  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00140152
I0510 21:42:52.918493  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.81789 (* 1 = 8.81789 loss)
I0510 22:00:09.519151  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 4000, Testing net (#0)
I0510 22:09:13.918016  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00149621
I0510 22:09:13.918102  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.80909 (* 1 = 8.80909 loss)
I0510 22:09:15.127683  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 4000, loss = 8.8597
I0510 22:09:15.127722  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.8597 (* 1 = 8.8597 loss)
I0510 22:09:15.127729  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 4000, lr = 0.001
I0510 22:28:39.320019  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 5000, Testing net (#0)
I0510 22:37:43.847064  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00118371
I0510 22:37:43.847173  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.80527 (* 1 = 8.80527 loss)
I0510 23:58:17.120088  3591 solver.cpp:454] Snapshotting to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_10000.caffemodel
I0510 23:58:17.238307  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:273] Snapshotting solver state to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_10000.solverstate
I0510 23:58:17.491825  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 10000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 00:02:19.412715  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00186553
I0511 00:02:19.412762  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.79114 (* 1 = 8.79114 loss)
I0511 00:02:19.986547  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 10000, loss = 8.83457
I0511 00:02:19.986570  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.83457 (* 1 = 8.83457 loss)
I0511 00:02:19.986578  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 10000, lr = 0.001
I0511 00:11:55.546052  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 11000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 00:15:57.490486  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00164773
I0511 00:15:57.490532  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.78702 (* 1 = 8.78702 loss)
I0511 00:25:33.666496  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 12000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 00:29:35.603062  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.0016572
I0511 00:29:35.603109  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.7848 (* 1 = 8.7848 loss)
I0511 00:29:36.177078  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 12000, loss = 9.00561
I0511 00:29:36.177105  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 9.00561 (* 1 = 9.00561 loss)
I0511 00:29:36.177114  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 12000, lr = 0.001
I0511 00:39:11.729369  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 13000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 00:43:13.678067  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.001875
I0511 00:43:13.678113  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.78359 (* 1 = 8.78359 loss)
I0511 00:52:49.851985  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 14000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 00:56:51.767343  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00154356
I0511 00:56:51.767390  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77998 (* 1 = 8.77998 loss)
I0511 00:56:52.341564  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 14000, loss = 8.83385
I0511 00:56:52.341591  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.83385 (* 1 = 8.83385 loss)
I0511 00:56:52.341598  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 14000, lr = 0.001
I0511 02:14:38.224290  3591 solver.cpp:454] Snapshotting to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_20000.caffemodel
I0511 02:14:38.735008  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:273] Snapshotting solver state to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_20000.solverstate
I0511 02:14:38.805809  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 20000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 02:18:40.681993  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00179924
I0511 02:18:40.682086  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.78129 (* 1 = 8.78129 loss)
I0511 02:18:41.255969  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 20000, loss = 8.82502
I0511 02:18:41.255995  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.82502 (* 1 = 8.82502 loss)
I0511 02:18:41.256001  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 20000, lr = 0.001
I0511 04:30:58.924096  3591 solver.cpp:454] Snapshotting to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_30000.caffemodel
I0511 04:31:00.742739  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:273] Snapshotting solver state to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_30000.solverstate
I0511 04:31:01.151980  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 30000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 04:35:03.075263  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00186553
I0511 04:35:03.075307  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77867 (* 1 = 8.77867 loss)
I0511 04:35:03.649479  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 30000, loss = 8.82915
I0511 04:35:03.649507  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.82915 (* 1 = 8.82915 loss)
I0511 04:35:03.649513  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 30000, lr = 0.001
I0511 07:55:36.848265  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 45000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 07:59:38.834043  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00179924
I0511 07:59:38.834095  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77432 (* 1 = 8.77432 loss)
I0511 09:03:48.141854  3591 solver.cpp:454] Snapshotting to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_50000.caffemodel
I0511 09:03:49.736464  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:273] Snapshotting solver state to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_50000.solverstate
I0511 09:03:49.797582  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 50000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 09:07:51.777150  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.001875
I0511 09:07:51.777207  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77058 (* 1 = 8.77058 loss)
I0511 09:07:52.351323  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 50000, loss = 9.11435
I0511 09:07:52.351351  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 9.11435 (* 1 = 9.11435 loss)
I0511 09:07:52.351357  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 50000, lr = 0.001
I0511 09:17:28.188742  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 51000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 09:21:30.200623  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00186553
I0511 09:21:30.200716  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77026 (* 1 = 8.77026 loss)
I0511 09:31:06.596501  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 52000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 09:35:08.580215  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00182765
I0511 09:35:08.580313  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76917 (* 1 = 8.76917 loss)
I0511 09:35:09.154428  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 52000, loss = 8.89758
I0511 09:35:09.154453  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.89758 (* 1 = 8.89758 loss)
I0511 09:35:09.154459  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 52000, lr = 0.001
I0511 09:44:44.906309  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 53000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 09:48:46.866353  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00185606
I0511 09:48:46.866430  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.7708 (* 1 = 8.7708 loss)
I0511 09:58:23.097244  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 54000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 10:02:25.056555  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00192235
I0511 10:02:25.056605  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76884 (* 1 = 8.76884 loss)
I0511 10:02:25.630312  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 54000, loss = 8.90552
I0511 10:02:25.630337  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.90552 (* 1 = 8.90552 loss)
I0511 10:02:25.630342  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 54000, lr = 0.001
I0511 14:44:51.563555  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 75000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 14:48:53.573640  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.0016572
I0511 14:48:53.573724  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76967 (* 1 = 8.76967 loss)
I0511 14:58:30.080453  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 76000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 15:02:32.076011  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.001875
I0511 15:02:32.076077  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.7695 (* 1 = 8.7695 loss)
I0511 15:02:32.650342  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 76000, loss = 9.0084
I0511 15:02:32.650367  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 9.0084 (* 1 = 9.0084 loss)
I0511 15:02:32.650373  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 76000, lr = 0.001
I0511 15:12:08.597450  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 77000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 15:16:10.636613  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00181818
I0511 15:16:10.636693  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76889 (* 1 = 8.76889 loss)
I0511 15:25:47.167667  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 78000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 15:29:49.204596  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00185606
I0511 15:29:49.204649  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77059 (* 1 = 8.77059 loss)
I0511 15:29:49.779094  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 78000, loss = 8.73139
I0511 15:29:49.779119  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.73139 (* 1 = 8.73139 loss)
I0511 15:29:49.779124  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 78000, lr = 0.001
I0511 15:39:25.730358  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 79000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 15:43:27.756417  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00192235
I0511 15:43:27.756485  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76846 (* 1 = 8.76846 loss)
I0511 15:53:04.419961  3591 solver.cpp:454] Snapshotting to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_80000.caffemodel
I0511 15:53:06.138357  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:273] Snapshotting solver state to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_80000.solverstate
I0511 15:53:06.519551  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 80000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 15:57:08.719681  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00164773
I0511 15:57:08.719737  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77126 (* 1 = 8.77126 loss)
I0511 15:57:09.294163  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 80000, loss = 8.56576
I0511 15:57:09.294188  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.56576 (* 1 = 8.56576 loss)
I0511 15:57:09.294193  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 80000, lr = 0.001
I0511 17:01:19.190099  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 85000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 17:05:21.148668  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00185606
I0511 17:05:21.148733  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77196 (* 1 = 8.77196 loss)
I0511 17:14:57.670343  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 86000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 17:18:59.659850  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00181818
I0511 17:18:59.659907  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77126 (* 1 = 8.77126 loss)
I0511 17:19:00.234335  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 86000, loss = 8.72875
I0511 17:19:00.234359  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.72875 (* 1 = 8.72875 loss)
I0511 17:19:00.234364  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 86000, lr = 0.001
I0511 17:28:36.196920  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 87000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 17:32:38.181174  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00181818
I0511 17:32:38.181231  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.771 (* 1 = 8.771 loss)
I0511 17:42:14.658293  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 88000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 17:46:16.614358  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00188447
I0511 17:46:16.614415  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76964 (* 1 = 8.76964 loss)
I0511 17:46:17.188212  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 88000, loss = 8.80409
I0511 17:46:17.188233  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.80409 (* 1 = 8.80409 loss)
I0511 17:46:17.188240  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 88000, lr = 0.001
I0511 17:55:53.358322  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 89000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 17:59:55.305763  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00186553
I0511 17:59:55.305868  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76909 (* 1 = 8.76909 loss)
I0511 18:09:31.658655  3591 solver.cpp:454] Snapshotting to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_90000.caffemodel
I0511 18:09:33.138741  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:273] Snapshotting solver state to binary proto file /home/wang/caffe-master/examples/NN2_iter_90000.solverstate
I0511 18:09:33.691995  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 90000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 18:13:35.626065  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00168561
I0511 18:13:35.626148  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.76973 (* 1 = 8.76973 loss)
I0511 18:13:36.200448  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 90000, loss = 8.97326
I0511 18:13:36.200469  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.97326 (* 1 = 8.97326 loss)
I0511 18:13:36.200474  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 90000, lr = 0.001
I0511 19:31:23.715662  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 96000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 19:35:25.677780  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00188447
I0511 19:35:25.677836  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.7695 (* 1 = 8.7695 loss)
I0511 19:35:26.251850  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 96000, loss = 8.74232
I0511 19:35:26.251875  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.74232 (* 1 = 8.74232 loss)
I0511 19:35:26.251880  3591 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 96000, lr = 0.001
I0511 19:45:02.057610  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 97000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 19:49:04.029269  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00188447
I0511 19:49:04.029357  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77655 (* 1 = 8.77655 loss)
I0511 19:58:40.265120  3591 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 98000, Testing net (#0)
I0511 20:02:42.182787  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00183712
I0511 20:02:42.182859  3591 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 8.77069 (* 1 = 8.77069 loss)
I0511 20:02:42.756922  3591 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 98000, loss = 8.61745
I0511 20:02:42.756944  3591 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 8.61745 (* 1 = 8.61745 loss)
```

Duo to the limit of characters of codes, I have to delete some rows of the log. However, it doesn’t matter.　
As you can see, there is no difference between  "*Iteration 98000*" and "*Iteration 0*". I am really puzzled with this situation.

This is the architecture of my model

```
name: "NN2"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    mean_file :"/home/jiayi-wei/caffe/examples/NN2/image_train_mean.binaryproto"  
  data_param {
    source: "/home/jiayi-wei/caffe/examples/NN2/img_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 30
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    mean_file :"/home/jiayi-wei/caffe/examples/NN2/image_train_mean.binaryproto"
  data_param {
    source: "/home/jiayi-wei/caffe/examples/NN2/img_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 11
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
#first layers
layer {
  name: "conv11"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv11"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu11" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv11"
  top: "conv11"
}
layer {
  name: "conv12"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv11"
  top: "conv12"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu12" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv12"
  top: "conv12"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv12"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
#second layers
layer {
  name: "conv21"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv21"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu21" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv21"
  top: "conv21"
}
layer {
  name: "conv22"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv21"
  top: "conv22"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu22" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv22"
  top: "conv22"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv22"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
#third layers
layer {
  name: "conv31"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv31"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu31" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv31"
  top: "conv31"
}
layer {
  name: "conv32"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv31"
  top: "conv32"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu32" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv32"
  top: "conv32"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv32"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
#fourth layer
layer {
  name: "conv41"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "conv41"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu41" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv41"
  top: "conv41"
}
layer {
  name: "conv42"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv41"
  top: "conv42"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu42" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv42"
  top: "conv42"
}
layer {
  name: "conv43"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv42"
  top: "conv43"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu43" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv43"
  top: "conv43"
}
layer {
  name: "pool4"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv43"
  top: "pool4"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
#fiveth layer
layer {
  name: "conv51"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "conv51"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu51" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv51"
  top: "conv51"
}
layer {
  name: "conv52"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv51"
  top: "conv52"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu52" 
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv52"
  top: "conv52"
}
layer {
  name: "conv53"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv52"
  top: "conv53"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv53"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: AVE
    pad:1
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}

#drop_Fc
layer {
  name: "dropout"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "pool5"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output:1000
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output:10575
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc7"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "SoftMax"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc7"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "SoftMax"
}
```

Following is my solver. And i have change base_lr to *＂0.001＂*

```
net: "train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 10000
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: ０．００１
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "/home/jiayi-wei/caffe/examples/NN2"
solver_mode: GPU
```

I have tried to change some parametric and I have already tried to reduce a "conv" layer from the block who has three "conv" layers. However the result always keep like the picture shows.

Please tell me how can i make out the problem? thanks

Comment: `num_output:10575` Are your trying to classify 10575 classes?!

Comment: the database i use is CASIA WebFace（http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/english/CASIA-WebFace-Database.html）who include 10575 classes

Comment: @Anoop K. Prabhu did you mean that the large number of classes induce my problem?

Comment: No no, not at all. I was just cross checking whether the prototxt file is correct. The transform parameter of input data has a typo: `mirror: ture` instead of `mirror: true`

Comment: Share the complete output log file as a text instead of a screenshot, so that we could understand the behavior of your training better.

Comment: shame for my carelessness, however the code which runs on my machine  does not have this wrong. OK i will share my log immediately.

Comment: i forget to record  log for my model as this is my first time to train my own model. But i have added "tee  model.log" in my train.sh. I can share the log file tomorrow.

Comment: If you are planning to run the training again to save the log, its better to reduce the `base_lr` value too to something like `0.0001`.

Comment: I have shared my log and I have changed  base_lr from 0.01 to 0.001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your log, it seems that your model tended to keep predicting label unchangingly during training and namely, your training diverged. I advise you to make the following check.

1. Check out your label when convert train/validation lmdb data and in your CNN architechure, the Dropout layer is better placed under the InnerProduct layer, namely "fc6", instead of Pooling layer, "pool5".
2. I don't know how you sampled your training data during training. In principle, if you just use Softmax cost(multi-nominal cross entropy loss), you should shuffle your train data when prepare your train/val lmdb data and set a properly large **batch size**, for example 256 during training.
3. Maybe your learn rate(base_lr) was too large, you may further reduce your learn rate from 0.001 to 0.0001, but I noticed that the CASIA WebFace baseline(http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7923) used a 0.01 learning rate, and the input data scale, active function, the depth and width of your model is similar to that, so it was less possibly caused by learn rate.(but you should  check whether the weight initializing method matters much.)
4. Try a smaller convolutional kernel size. Sometimes this may help due to reducing the information loss resulting from the alignment problem between convolution kernel and its corresponding input feature map.

By the way, you are training a task of classifying 10575 classes with every class only having about 40 training samples, so to some extent, training data is insufficient. So like work in the base line, to enhance the model's ability to distinguish the same and the different samples, it's better to add a **Contrastive cost** besides a Softmax cost.

Reference
   Sun Y, Chen Y, Wang X, et al. Deep learning face representation by joint identification-verification[C]//Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems. 2014: 1988-1996.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I would like to adjust my caffe-model as your suggestions.

Comment: I advise you to first reproduce the  train of the CASIA WebFace baseline to make sure that all your train config is right and then try to change the CNN model architecture step by step.

Comment: I have to say that your suggestions did not work on my situation.And I sent   an email to the paper author, however there was no feedback.  The model architecture maybe has something wrong.As a last resort, another model architecture was selected. However, your advice is suitable for such problem.I am really grateful for your hand.

Answer (score 1):

Your `base_lr` seems to be high. Start with a `base_lr`of `0.001` and go on reducing it by a factor of 10 whenever you stop seeing improvement in accuracy for several thousand iterations.

NOTE: This is just a rule of thumb, it may not work in all cases.

Comment: However i have change my base_lr to 0.001. It made no difference.